# Getting error while getting Product by Varient Id in Angular js and Shopify Graph QL

Tags: angular, angularjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

```
async getProductByVarientId(varientid, pId = null) {
    const client = this.client;
    let query = client.query((root) => {
        root.add('node', { args: { id: varientid }, alias: 'productvariant' }, (node) => {
            node.add('id');
            node.addInlineFragmentOn('ProductVariant', (variants) => {
                variants.add('id');
                variants.add('product');
                variants.add('title');
                variants.add('price');
                // variants.add('price', (price) => {
                //  price.add('amount');
                //  price.add('currencyCode');
                // });
                variants.add('image', (image) => {
                    image.add('src');
                    image.add('id');
                    image.add('altText');
                });
            });
        });
    });

    return await client.send(query).then(({ model, data }) => {
        console.log('>++++++++', model);
        // Check if 'productvariant' is defined before accessing its properties
        return (model && model.productvariant) ? model.productvariant : '';
    });
}
```

I was trying to get the product details by varient Id, this code was working fine from last 1 year.
This code is written in AngularJs with Shopify Graph QL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpsNo.png)